# promise testing in angular

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I want to test the following method in my controller class:

```
//  getIds() {
//  this.api.getIds()
//    .then((response)=> {
//      this.ids = response.data;
//      this.doSomethingElse();
//    });
//  }
```

I'm not sure how to handle the promise using jasmine and karma. The project is written in ES6. `api.getIds()` returns a $http.get().

```
beforeEach(function() {

    inject(function($controller, $rootScope, _api_) {

      vm = $controller('MainController', {
        api: _api_,
        $scope:$rootScope.$new()
      });

    });
});

beforeEach(function () {
  vm.getIds();
});

it('should set the ids', function () {
  expect(vm.ids).toBeDefined(); //error
});
```

How do I wait for the promise to complete before running the expect() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should use the `done` callback provided by the jasmine; see [async support in Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support).

Then, you should mock your `getIds` on the `api` so that it returns a resolved promise with an expected value. The asserts should be done after the `then` promise is called - se bellow the full example.

```
  beforeEach(function () {
    var $q, vm, api, $controller, $rootScope;

    inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$q_) {
      $q = _$q_;
      $controller = _$controller_;
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_;

      api = jasmine.createSpyObj('api', ['getIds']);
      api.getIds.and.returnValue($q.when([]));

      vm = $controller('MainController', {
        api: api,
        $scope: $rootScope.$new()
      });
    });
  });

  it('should set the ids', function (done) {
    vm
      .getIds()
      .then(function (ids) {
        expect(ids).toBeDefined();
        // add more asserts
        done();
      });
  });
```

As a side note, if the `this.doSomethingElse();` is a promise too, you have to return it in the first `then` so that you can test the final result.